# Custom Expression Tree Visitor - How do I get the UnaryExpression node's value?

Tags: c#, expression-trees

I have an override for the Unary Visitor which seems to be working well, but I need to get the value of the operand from the node.

If it is a ConstantExpression, it is quite easy to achieve:

```
var value = ((ConstantExpression) node.Operand).Value;
```

The question is how to achieve this if the node is a MemberExpression with a value type like an int:

```
protected override Expression VisitUnary(UnaryExpression node)
{                 
    //get the value stored in the node.Operand     
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no guarantee that an `UnaryExpression` is connected to a constant value... In `x => (int)x` for example `(int)` is an `UnaryExpression` that isn't connected to a constant value.

But... you can check if it is...

```
// Unravel (object)(long)5
while (node.Operand is UnaryExpression)
{
    node = (UnaryExpression)node.Operand;
}

ConstantExpression ce = node.Operand as ConstantExpression;

if (ce != null)
{
    // success!
    object value = ce.Value;
}
```